# Java - JPA : ManyToOne join table not updated

Tags: java, jpa

I want to make a join table from the table Projets(idprojets PK,contrats) with Contracts(idcontrats PK, contrat_name). The final table would be JoinProjetsContrats(idprojet,idcontrat)

Here's my code so far:

```
 Projet 

@Entity
@Table(name="projets")
public class Projet implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="PROJETS_IDPROJET_GENERATOR", sequenceName="PROJETS_IDPROJET_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PROJETS_IDPROJET_GENERATOR")
    private Integer idprojet;
    @Column(name="charge_totale")
    private double chargeTotale;

    private String intitule;

    private String statut;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Contrat
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idcontrat")
    private Contrat contrat;

Contrat:

@Entity
@Table(name="contrats")
public class Contrat implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CONTRATS_IDCONTRAT_GENERATOR", sequenceName="CONTRATS_IDCONTRAT_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CONTRATS_IDCONTRAT_GENERATOR")
    private Integer idcontrat;
    private String nom;
    //uni-directional many-to-many association to Projet
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="\"joinProjetsContrats\""
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="idcontrats")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="idprojets")
            }
        )
    private Set<Projet> projets1;
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Projet
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="contrat")
    private Set<Projet> projets2;
```

I guess there's something missing here, since the update is not made in my SQL table when I create a "projet". Projet table is updated.

Any ideas of the mistake I've missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show also the other Entity side with `@OneToMany`

Comment: From contrats.java

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Projet
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy="contributeurs")
 private Set<Projet> projets;

Comment: So why is there a `@ManyToOne`? Your question is not realy clear - or your setup

Comment: I don't know what I have to change then, changing ManyToMany to OneToMany doesn't do anything

Comment: Please show both parts of both entities. So I want to see the `Contract` side, too

Comment: Done, I updated the OP

Comment: on `@JoinColumn` you need to add the DB-Fieldname, not the Entity one. So look for the real DB name or annotate with `@Column(name="idcontrat")`
Default PK name is just ID. [EXAMPLE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne)

Comment: according to my DB, I changed my code to:
projet:
 @JoinColumn(name="idcontrat")
contrat:
name="\"joinProjetsContrats\""
  , joinColumns={
   @JoinColumn(name="idcontrat")
   }
  , inverseJoinColumns={
   @JoinColumn(name="idprojet")
   }

but it does not work

Comment: Just use manyToOne+joinColoumn+column(name on id) and other side oneToMany(mappedBy=fieldName)

Comment: on the onetomany side, I tried just : @OneToMany(mappedBy="contrat") but doesnt do anything either